# How to do X when a job hits respawn limit

Tags: upstart

I have a service named `manager`, which sometimes updates itself (from some network location). If something wrong happens during this update, like a system shutdown, I want to replace the bad executable with a known-working one. This resulted in me having two Upstart jobs.

The main job file:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/manager
start on startup
respawn
```

The watchdog job file:

```
start on stopping manager PROCESS="respawn"
script
    WATCHED="manager"
    EXE="/usr/local/bin/$WATCHED"
    cp /usr/local/var/"$WATCHED".bk $EXE
    chmod +x $EXE
    start $WATCHED
end script
```

2 questions:

- Is this a fine approach... can it be improved?
- Is there a way to do all this in just one job file?

Comment: First thing that pops out is this: You're replacing the binary whenever the `manager` job goes down, instead of after n failures (like the title implies). If you're doing that, why not use a `post-stop`/`pre-start` combo?

Comment: No, it only gets replaced after n failures. Thats what `PROCESS="respawn"` does.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about `PROCESS="respawn"`. Still, why not use `pre-start` instead? Something like: `pre-start script    if [ "$PROCESS" = "respawn" ]; then blah; fi   end script`? -- Scratch that. Looking at the cookbook, I think your current way is right.

Comment: Am curious: if I were to use `pre-start`, would that live in the watchdog job file?